# How can you get and manipulate data from a plugin in a grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana

How can you create a query in Grafana that gets the data from an installed plugin?

In my specific case, I would like to receive the data from the [alert-list plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/alertlist/), change it using transformations and integrate it into my own panel.

Comment: I don't think this plugin allows extraction of the data. Maybe you can use something like [JSON API plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/) to extract data from grafana's api, but I'm not sure.